# angular $window directive applied to multiple dom elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've spent today trying my hand at my first directive, and it works to a point, but I need more.

The idea is that my app will have some looong tables, with nested tables. I'd like to be able to anchor the thead of the table you are currently viewing to the top of the page as you scroll down, so you can always match data to header. I have managed to get the first header to work:

[plunker example working on one thead](http://plnkr.co/edit/7HyizAeruvgXWvTLEWFv?p=preview).

What I would like to do, but I just cannot work out, is how to have this directive apply to multiple table headers (so that the nested headers also anchor as you scroll).

To do this I have the directive now creating a parent object with a child object for each of the headers it needs to work with. Problem is I can't work out how to get the directive to watch for changes to the $window scrolls:

[plunker example of where it's currently at (and broken)](http://plnkr.co/edit/7HyizAeruvgXWvTLEWFv?p=preview)

as you can see, I very much struggled with concept of scope within the directive (but it seems to all work up to this point) and once it get's to this point, it's no longer dealing with the correct object anymore

```
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
          stickyHeads[i].elTop = stickyHeads[i].el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
          if ((stickyHeads[i].elTop <= glueToY) && (stickyHeads[i].inView === true)) {
            stickyHeads[i].inView = false;
            showHead(stickyHeads[i].newEl);
          };
          if (stickyHeads[i].elTop >= glueToY) {
            stickyHeads[i].inView = true;
            hideHead(stickyHeads[i].newEl);
          };
        });
```

Can anyone give me some advice on this please? I considered getting the offset.top of each table, and making the $window.scroll just fire a change if it meets one of these values, would that make sense? Or is there some other angularey way that I'm completely missing?

---

EDIT: I MADE IT WORK!

so I found that if I iterate through the stickyHeads object on the scroll event I can get angular to assess the offset().top of each element and hide/show as I need it to.

[Updated plunker with working solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/7HyizAeruvgXWvTLEWFv?p=preview)

I also added a (crude and ugly) box shadow and offset to each extra header as it gets fixed to the top of the page, so you can see them stacking up.

I next need to make them disappear again if you scroll past the bottom of the table, but I think that should not be too hard.